# from .html to no .html angular

Tags: html, angularjs, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

so basically I've this htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on  
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
   RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
   #RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

but old website has all the .html url's like www.mysite.com/contact.html

thing is it's first page in a lot of google searches and i don't want to loose all that indexed pages, so i what i want is to get that and remove the .html

also, i've custom url's like www.mysite.com/product/whatever_my_name.html
same story, grab that and make it www.mysite.com/product/whatever_my_name

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^((?:/[^/]+)+).html$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [NS,L,R=301]
```

Testing only the client's request is important to avoid interference with serving any other html docs, e.g. your main `index.html`.